# differential on total chain complex

Tags: homological-algebra

There is the definition of (second) total chain complex of double complex of chains from GTM 004.He says $(\partial b)_{p,q}=\partial'b_{p+1,q}+\partial''b_{p,q+1}$,but I don't have any clues what $b_{p+1,q},b_{p,q+1}$ are.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element of the total complex consists of a choice of an element
$b_{p,q}\in B_{p,q}$ for each pair of integers $p$ and $q$. We need
to define what its boundary is. The definition is that is consists of the
elements $c_{p,q}$ determined by the formula
$$c_{p,q}=\partial'b_{p+1,q}+\partial''b_{p,q+1}.$$
As $b_{p+1,q}\in B_{p+1,q}$ then $\partial'b_{p+1,q}\in B_{p,q}$ etc., so that
$c_{p,q}\in B_{p,q}$.